# How can I check if Quartz Extreme is supported?

Tags: java, macos, quartz-graphics

**Question:**
Is there any way to check if Quartz Extreme is supported on a mac by using java?

I had a hunt around, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to go about checking this.

**Reason:**
I am using a library that requires Quartz Extreme to play video files correctly on OSX.
If Quartz Extreme is not supported then I will prevent the program from running the video files rather than spitting out errors or running very slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mandatory to run Mac OS 10.6 or later, and, as such, is supported on all Intel Macs. Unless you are specifically writing an application which needs to run on older PowerPC Macs, you can safely assume that QE is always available.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1582

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have seen rare cases where this isn't the case with 10.6 (Custom built boxes, virtual machines etc) but that is not normal so is not a huge problem. If anyone was interested I will use this to check for a PowerPC `System.getProperty("os.arch").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ppc")` so I can prevent video playback when the value is true.